# I have read that a design which fails signal integrity shall have EMC issues

Tags: emc, signal-integrity

I have read that if a design has EMC issues and is emitting a lot of radiation, then there is a relationship with some signal paths not being properly terminated and/or there being signal integrity issues on the PCB. To what extent is this true?

Comment: Of course there are things (such as switching supplies) that have nothing to do with signals, let alone signal integrity, and can emit a lot of EMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen EMC emission issues stemming from unterminated traces.

I have however seen several cases of EMC emission issues stemming from poor design of the bypassing and power distribution system.

You can count power integrity (PI) as being part of signal integrity (SI), so to that extent yes there is a correlation.